# SSRS custom color for line graph

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I enter in the following code in the line color property, and it makes the line I want pink. The other lines though, are all black. I set the color palette to default, so shouldnt it use a color from that palette and not black? Am I missing something?

```
=SWITCH(
   Fields!Manufacturer.Value = "Cisco LAB", "HotPink"
   )
```

Comment: Are you looking to change all of your lines to pink?

Comment: No. Just one line for the grouping "Cisco Lab". All of the other lines should be from the default palette.

Comment: If you navigate to the Series Properties of the other (black) lines, and go to the 'Fill' page, what value is in the 'Color:' field? Make sure its set to 'Automatic' (#00000000).

Comment: That is where I put my custom code at.

Comment: It seems to be working for me. If you change the color palette to a different style, do you see the colors change in the Design view?

Comment: Yes I can see them change.

Comment: And then when you run the report, all of the lines that aren't pink turn black, correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Any idea what would be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
=IIF(Fields!Manufacturer.Value = "Cisco LAB", "HotPink", 'Automatic')
```